# Episodes index for Terminator - The Sarah Connor Chronicles - The Complete First Season on Blu-Ray

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

I just started to watch [Terminator - The Sarah Connor Chronicles - The Complete First Season on Blu-Ray](http://amzn.com/B00168HARG) :

[image: Terminator - The Sarah Connor Chronicles - The Complete First Season on Blu-Ray]

As soon as I put the first Disk in my player, it started with the first episode. That was good until I stopped it and came back to watch the second episode the day after. It started the first episode again, so I went to the menu to select the second episode, but *niet!*, *nada!*, no episode selection menu! Just a bunch of *special features* and a *Resume Episode* entry. I checked if there was a booklet, no luck. I had to resume the episode and skip scene, one by one, until I reach the start of the second episode!

Now that I have to live with this disk setup, could someone provide me an episodes index, to know which episode is on which disk? That way I wont have to skip all episode to notice at the end that, no, I need to put the next disk. That would be great to also have it for the second season, if the menu is crappy as the one of the first season.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right [here](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Season_1_DVD) and [here](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Season_2_DVD) for the DVD release.  I don't know if the Blu-Ray is different:

**Season 1**

- Disc 1:

  - "Pilot", Terminated Scenes, Commentary
  - "Gnothi Seauton"
  - "The Turk", Terminated Scene, Commentary
  - Special Features: 3-part "Creating the Chronicles"; Gag Reel
- Disc 2:

  - "Heavy Metal"
  - "Queen's Gambit"
  - "Dungeons & Dragons", Terminated Scene
  - Special Features: Cast Audition Tapes; School Attack Animatic; Summer Glau dance rehearsal
- Disc 3:

  - "The Demon Hand", Terminated Scenes
  - "Vick's Chip"
  - "What He Beheld", Commentary
  - Special Features: "The Demon Hand" 52-minute Extended Cut

**Season 2**

- Disc 1:

  - "Samson & Delilah" - Commentary
  - "Automatic for the People"
  - "The Mousetrap"
  - "Allison from Palmdale" - Commentary
  - The Storyboard Process: Cameron Goes Bad
- Disc 2:

  - "Goodbye to All That"
  - "The Tower Is Tall But the Fall Is Short" - Terminated Scene
  - "Brothers of Nablus"
  - "Mr. Ferguson is Ill Today"
  - Cameron Vs. Rosie Fight Rehearsal
- Disc 3:

  - "Complications" - Terminated Scene
  - "Strange Things Happen at the One Two Point" - Terminated Scene
  - "Self Made Man"
  - "Alpine Fields"
- Disc 4:

  - "Earthlings Welcome Here" - Terminated Scene
  - "The Good Wound"
  - "Desert Cantos"
  - "Some Must Watch, While Some Must Sleep"
- Disc 5:

  - "Ourselves Alone"
  - "Today Is The Day, Part 1" - Terminated Scene
  - "Today Is The Day, Part 2" - Terminated Scenes
  - "To the Lighthouse" - Terminated Scenes
- Disc 6:

  - "Adam Raised a Cain" - Commentary
  - "Born to Run" - Commentary, Terminated Scene
  - Special Features *emphasized text*

Comment: I will print this and come back with retaliation if there is any difference with the Blu-Ray.

Comment: @DavRob60  I think posting your own Blu-Ray answer will suffice  =P  (But why not, whenever you finish an episode, check that the next one exists on the disc at that time and remember for next time?)

Comment: That what I did until now, but I fear to forget about it.